# The findAncestorStateOfType is returning null as a value

Tags: flutter

My code :

```dart
   class NavPage extends StatefulWidget {

    NavPage({@required this.name, @required this.id});

    static void setLocale(BuildContext context, Locale locale) {
    _NavPageState state = context.findAncestorStateOfType<_NavPageState>();
    print(state);/* printed as null because findAncestorStateOfType  returned null*/

    state.setLocale(locale);
  }

  @override
  _NavPageState createState() => _NavPageState();
}
```

Error:

```dart
I/flutter (10132): null
E/flutter (10132): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'setLocale' was called on null.
E/flutter (10132): Receiver: null
```

So here I was trying to internationalize my app but I faced this problem in the last stages of coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think where you would want to call the **state** object would be after the build method actually

See this for more insight

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/findAncestorStateOfType.html

Method not before it.

Comment: I tried this solution but the issue remained the same...

Comment: Anybody can help please?